# Getting results from nested json with variable dict keys in python

Tags: python, json, nested, range, python-3.8

I would like to extract "date", "account", "extended_tweet" and "location" from a nested json file with variable dict keys from 1 to 500.

How can I loop with my code snippet through all 500 dicts in Python 3.8?

I get only 500 times the same result for the first dict right now.

```
data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()

for i in list(range(0, 501)):
    date = data['1']['created_at']
    account = data['1']['user']['name']
    extended_tweet = data['1']['retweeted_status']['extended_tweet']['full_text']
    location = data['1']['user']['location']
    print(date, account, extended_tweet, location)
```

Comment: well you used `data['1']` so you're always going to get the first dict in data

Comment: Check out what the index variable in a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) is for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
for i in range(1, 501):
    date = data[str(i)]['created_at']
    account = data[str(i)]['user']['name']
    extended_tweet = data[str(i)]['retweeted_status']['extended_tweet']['full_text']
    location = data[str(i)]['user']['location']
    print(date, account, extended_tweet, location)
```

Faults in your code  :

1. You were looping through the range, but were not using the loop counter to get the exact key. You need to get the keys `'1'`, `'2'`,... for loops, but were using same `'1'` each time.
2. You need to use `range(1, 501)`, in stead you were doing `range(0, 501)` which will be trying to get the key for `'0'` too.
3. Improvement, not a fault : you don't need to use `list(range())`; in stead you can directly use `range()` for looping.